# I'm having an issue displaying changes to the surface using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My current goal is to make a smaller circle rotate around the center of a larger circle and have the rectangles follow the path of the smaller circle.

I have created a `TargetCircle` class because there will be a total of 18 circles when this visualization is finished. 
My issue is that after changing the `theta` value for each circle and trying to display the changes, nothing happens.

Currently, all that gets displayed is the 9 circles across the top and the horizontal and vertical lines, however, everything remains stationary. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```py
import pygame as pg
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math

pg.init()
windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 800
surface = pg.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pg.display.set_caption("Circle")
clock = pg.time.Clock()
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
gray = (50, 50, 50)
red = (255, 0, 0)


class TargetCircle(object):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.circlePositionX = posX
        self.circlePositionY = posY
        self.radius = 38
        self.theta = 0
        self.x = int((self.circlePositionX + (self.radius * math.cos(self.theta))))
        self.y = int((self.circlePositionY + (self.radius * math.sin(self.theta))))

    def draw(self, win):
        pg.draw.rect(win, gray, (0, self.y, 800, 1))
        pg.draw.rect(win, gray, (self.x, 0, 1, 800))
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(win, self.circlePositionX, self.circlePositionY, self.radius, white)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(win, self.x, self.y, 2, white)


circleList = []
x = 120
for i in range(1, 10):
    circle = TargetCircle(x, 40)
    circle.draw(surface)
    circleList.append(circle)
    x += 80
pg.display.update()
loop = 0
run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(160)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    if loop == len(circleList):
        loop = 0

    surface.fill(0)
    for i in range(len(circleList)):
        circleList[i].theta += .10
        circleList[i].draw(surface)
    pg.display.flip()
    loop += 1

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not updating the x and y values of the `TargetCircle`. You set

```py
        self.x = int((self.circlePositionX + (self.radius * math.cos(self.theta))))
        self.y = int((self.circlePositionY + (self.radius * math.sin(self.theta))))
```

once in the `__init__` (which is called once at the start), and then it is never set again. To remedy this, move those two lines into `TargetCircle.draw` (which is called every frame):

```py
class TargetCircle(object):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.circlePositionX = posX
        self.circlePositionY = posY
        self.radius = 38
        self.theta = 0

    def draw(self, win):
        self.x = int((self.circlePositionX + (self.radius * math.cos(self.theta))))
        self.y = int((self.circlePositionY + (self.radius * math.sin(self.theta))))
        pg.draw.rect(win, gray, (0, self.y, 800, 1))
        pg.draw.rect(win, gray, (self.x, 0, 1, 800))
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(win, self.circlePositionX, self.circlePositionY, self.radius, white)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(win, self.x, self.y, 2, white)
```